# Receive message from main.js in Firefox add-on content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to communicate between `main.js` and a content script. Here is my `main.js`:

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
var self = require('sdk/self');
var ss = require('sdk/simple-storage');

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: 'example.com',
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url('content-script.js'),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on('getSetting', function(request) {
            // var settingValue = ss.storage[request]
            var settingValue = 'test value'; // for testing, return an 
                                             // arbitrary string
            worker.port.emit('settingRetrieved', settingValue);
        });
    }
});
```

And `content-script.js`:

```
alert('getting setting...');
self.port.emit('getSetting', 'test setting name');
alert('asked for setting...');
self.port.on('settingRetrieved', function(results) {
    alert('retrieved setting: "' + results + '"');
});
```

It appears that `self.port.on()` in `content-script.js` is not receiving the message from `main.js`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facepalm. The code from `content-script.js` was wrapped in a jQuery event handler, so `self.port.on()` couldn't listen properly.

Here is the working code--first, `main.js`:

```
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');
var self = require('sdk/self');
var ss = require('sdk/simple-storage');

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: 'example.com',
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url('content-script.js'),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on('getSetting', function(request) {
            var settingValue = ss.storage[request];
            worker.port.emit('settingRetrieved',
                {
                    'settingName': request,
                    'settingValue': settingValue,
                }
            );
        });
    }
});
```

And `content-script.js`:

```
// Store the setting value
var mySetting = '';

// Listen for retrieval the setting value
self.port.on('settingRetrieved', function(results) {
    mySetting = results['settingValue'];
});

// Generic function to retrieve a setting value
function getSetting(setting) {
    self.port.emit('getSetting', setting);
}

// Retrieve the value of 'mySetting' and do something with it
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-element').click(function() {
        getSetting('mySetting');
        /*
        ...
        Value of mySetting has been updated; do something with it here
        ...
        */
    });
});
```

Comment: Solved it agian! Thanks for sharing and dont feel bad these really help non-sdk devs, I can now help others better now that I have seen this.